# Has anyone tried to build/replicate deep sort (object tracking algo ) with TF_ver_2.x. without using tf.compat.v1.version ...?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Has anyone tried to build deep sort (object tracking algo ) compatible with TF_ver_2.x.

i.e.  generate_detections.py from https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort/tree/master/tools took a tflite version of mars-small128.pb and generate detections.
I did that using tf.compat.v1.version, but I need to change everything from scratch (every_function should be replaced by tf_2.x version, not by tf.compat.v1.version).

Also need to replace every_function of freeze_model.py with tf_2.x